# How will be Json Format for Complex type?

Tags: .net, json, entity-framework, json.net

I have created a RESTful wcf service which accepts and returns values in json format with following method:

```
public _1003Response<Response1003> Create1003Record(_1003Request request)
{
    var result = usrRep.Create1003Record(request);
    return result;
}

public class _1003Request
{          
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    public int CustomerTempReference { get; set; }
}
```

`Customer` Class type is generated by Entity Framework. I am testing my service using Poster tool in firefox. I don't know how to pass json format request for that? please help me out?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you asking how you can see the JSON returned result in "Poster"? I generally find Firebug works well for this.

Comment: using poster you can send json request to rest wcf service and recieve the same. it act as test client like SOAP UI. My Question is how to frame the format of Json for complex type like _1003Request.

Comment: Ohh, I see... one second. I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this as valid JSON:

```
var request = {
    Customer: {
      // everything in your Customer object here
      name: "Test"
    },
    CustomerTempReference: 0
}
```

You can then convert this to a string using:

```
var jsonRequest = JSON.stringify(request);
```

Comment: can you please make the above answer to look like {"" : ""  } in this format

Comment: hi chris , the request format is this? { "Customer":{"Custname":"rest"           },"CustomerTempReference":5 }.. unbale to pass this request pls clarifiy

Comment: hi when i pass the request { "Customer":{"Custname":"rest" },"CustomerTempReference":5 } the request is recieved is null .. pls note i m using enetiy fremwork class

Comment: Please make sure you're sending in the request with the data name of "_1003Request" so your Controller can pick it up.